# Как использовать методы классов, помещенных в HashMap?

Tags: java

Классы, помещенные в Map, реализуют интерфейс UserOption.

```
public class Menu {
    BasicConnectionPool basicConnectionPool;
    StudentDao studentDao;
    CourseDao courseDao;
    public Exit exit;
    Map<Integer, UserOption> userOptions;

    public Menu(BasicConnectionPool basicConnectionPool, StudentDao studentDao, CourseDao courseDao
    ) {
        userOptions = new HashMap<>();
        this.basicConnectionPool = basicConnectionPool;
        this.studentDao = studentDao;
        this.courseDao = courseDao;
        addOptions(basicConnectionPool, studentDao, courseDao);
    }

    private void addOptions(BasicConnectionPool basicConnectionPool, StudentDao studentDao, CourseDao courseDao) {
        userOptions.put(0, new AddStudent(studentDao));
        userOptions.put(1, new AddStudentToCourse(studentDao));
        userOptions.put(2, new DeleteStudent(studentDao));
        userOptions.put(3, new Exit(basicConnectionPool));
        userOptions.put(4, new RemoveStudentFromCourse(studentDao));
        userOptions.put(5, new SearchGroups(studentDao));
        userOptions.put(6, new SearchStudentsInCourse(courseDao));
    }
```

Нужно получить метод конкретного класса. Наивная попытка:

````
public void TODO() {
        userOptions.get(0).addStudentMethod("SOME PARAMS");
    }
    ```

структура класса
````

public class AddStudent implements UserOption{
StudentDao studentDao;

```
public AddStudent(StudentDao studentDao) {
    this.studentDao = studentDao;
}
public void addStudent(StudentDTO student) {
    studentDao.create(student);
}
```

}

Comment: Не называйте классы глаголами. Выберите подходящее существительное. Глаголы используйте для методов(void doSmth()).

Comment: метод get(ключ) дает значение -> userOptions.get(0).addStudentMethod("SOME PARAMS") должно работать. Убедитесь что методы публичны и правильно реализованы подклассами.

Comment: Выглядит как все ок. А какую ошибку дает IDEA?

Comment: "Cannot resolve method 'addStudent' in 'UserOption'". Проблема в том, что когда я достаю из мапы значения с классом, я могу использовать только методы, объявленные в самом интерфейсе, а мне нужно достать методы наследника.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void TODO() {
        userOptions.get(0).addStudentMethod("SOME PARAMS");
    }
```

В таком виде Java рассматривает нулевой член HashMapa как userOptions, а не как AddStudent. Соответственно, у userOptions нет метода addStudentMethod("SOME PARAMS"), так как он характерен только объектам класса AddStudent. Для того чтобы вызвать этот метод вам следует выполнить даункастинг. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
public void TODO() {
    AddStudent addStudent = (AddStudent) userOptions.get(0);
    addStudent.addStudentMethod("SOME PARAMS");
}
```

Вы даете понять Jave что нужно рассматривать этот объект как AddStudent, соответствено теперь вы сможете вызвать на нем метод, именно класса, а не интерфейса.

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось. Совсем не изящно, но думаю, таких ситуаций в целом быть не должно.